# Is $L^p$ linear for $0<p<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, lp-spaces

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Show that for all $0 <p< \infty$ the collections $L^p$ of measurable
> functions defined on a measure space $(X, \mathcal{M},μ)$ such that $ \int_X |f|^p d\mu < \infty$ are linear spaces. [Hint : Use the inequality $(a + b)^p ≤ 2^p(a^p + b^p)$.]

The spaces is closed for all $p$ under scalar multiplication but for closed under sum we use the hint : The case $x=0$ is obvious so letting $a>0$ and considering $x=a/b$, we have $f(x)=(x + 1)^p - 2^p(x^p + 1) \le 0$ holds for all $0\le x$ when $1 \le p$  but doesn't hold for $0<p<1$ *always*. So does really the claim fails for $0<p<1$ or I make mistakes?

So the question is about validity of $f(x)=(x + 1)^p - 2^p(x^p + 1) \le 0$ for $0<p<1$.

Comment: You need to prove something about functions in $L^p$ by integrating them.  Evaluating at specific values of $x$ is not going to get you there.

Comment: You did make mistakes. When $0<p<1$, one would have $(x+1)^p<x^p+1^p<2^p(x^p+1)$ since $x \ge 0$ and $2^p>1$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Evaluating at $x$ do help because one needs $|f+g|^p \le (|f|+|g|)^p < 2^p(|f|^p+|g|^p)$ everywhere and the monotonicity of integral to attain finiteness.

Comment: See the Wikipedia page for $L^p$-spaces and look at the section where $0<p<1$. The space of *measurable functions* $f$ that the textbook exercise defines is a vector space. The exercise is correct: the $p$th power of the usual $L^p$-norm formula (removing the overall $p$th root on the integral) is a metric when $0<p<1$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, no I want find the behavior of function but evaluating at some special points...

Comment: @Zerox I was confused about OP's statement “the case $x=0$ is obvious” and so on. I'm not sure how that matters.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

- For $0<p<1$: you have the inequality $(a+b)^p\leq a^p+b^p$ for all $a,b\geq0$. This can be proved by looking at $\phi(x)=(1+x)^p-x^p$. Using simple differential calculus you can show that $\phi(x)$ is monotone decreasing.
  Then, for $f,g\in L_p$ you have that
  $$\int|f+c g|^p\,d\mu\leq \int|f|^p\,d\mu + c^p\int|g|^p\,d\mu$$

**Observation:** unlike the case $p\geq1$, On spaces $L_p$ with $0<p<1$, $\Big(\int|f|^p\,d\mu\Big)^{1/p}$ is not a norm. However
$$ d(f,g):=\int|f-g|^p\,d\mu$$
does define a complete metric in such spaces.

- For $1\leq p$, if you know Jensen's inequality you can see that
  $x\mapsto x^p$ is convex and so, for $a,b\geq0$
  $$(a+b)^p=2^p\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)^p\leq 2^p\frac{a^p+b^p}{2}=2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$$

---

There are other simpler ways to del with the inequality in your hint. For example, for $a,b\geq0$, you have
$a+b\leq 2\max(a,b)$. As $x\mapsto x^p$ is increasing
$$(a+b)^p\leq 2^p\Big(\max(a,b)\Big)^p\leq 2^p(a^p+b^p)$$

Comment: @L.G. I guess you should consider then the last solution that proves your hint: the intermediate step is $2^p(\max(a,b))^p=2^p\max(a^p,b^p)\leq 2^p(a^p+b^p)$

Comment: $ \ \ $ Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Note:

1. For $0<p<+\infty$ , note that $x \mapsto x^p$ is an increasing function for $x \geq 0$.
2. For any $a, b> 0 $, $a+b  \leq 2 \max(a,b)$.

Combining 1 and 2, we have
$$ (a+b)^p  \leq 2^p \max(a,b)^p \leq 2^p (a^p +b^p)  \tag{1}$$

So we have proved that $(1)$ is true for any  $0<p<+\infty$ .

Now, using $(1)$, for any  $0<p<+\infty$ and $f, g \in L^p$, we have
$$\int |f +g|^p d \mu \leq \int (|f| + |g|)^p d \mu \leq \int 2^p(|f|^p + |g|^p) d \mu \leq 2^p \left ( \int |f|^p d \mu + \int |g|^p d \mu  \right ) < \infty$$
So $f+g \in L^p$.

**Remark**: Answering the last part of your question: "So the question is about validity of $f(x)=(x + 1)^p - 2^p(x^p + 1) \le 0$ for $0<p<1$".

From $(1)$, we have that, for any $0 <p < +\infty$, if $x >0$
then
$$ (x + 1)^p \leq 2^p(x^p + 1) $$
So  $f(x)=(x + 1)^p - 2^p(x^p + 1) \le 0$ for $0<p<1$.